# How to create an instruction in android app (directing a user to click a specific button)

Tags: java, android, xml, android-layout, android-dialogfragment

I am developing an android application and want to create an instruction mechanism for every page, directing users to click a specific button.

How can I create such dialogs indicating, highlighting a button that has to be clicked, a[image: As you can see at the left screen, I want such result]lso the button should be highlighted and background is darkened to focus a user's attention.

I created a simple alert dialog, but it's not what I am looking for

Comment: you can crete popup windows and show the same at a specific location on the screen or relative to the view you are highlighting. Search of show case views on github. there are plenty or search view tooltips android https://github.com/skydoves/Balloon

Comment: There are many libraries available publicly to make an "Guided tour" through the app: ex: https://github.com/canopas/Intro-showcase-view